# How to suppress vibration from computer to speaker?

Tags: audio, sound-card, speakers

My PC speaker (Logitech z523) is producing weird buzzing sounds which I think is caused by vibrations from my PC. It's connected to the on-board sound card. I tried putting a 3.5mm to 3.5mm jack between the speaker and the sound card in an attempt to suppress the vibration but it doesn't work.

Is there anyway I can fix this issue?

Comment: put the speaker or desktop on a softish surface? Maybe foam?

Comment: Are you sure "vibration" is the word you're looking for?  Like physical shaking of the surfaces?  To me, it sounds more like it may be grounding issues, or a ground loop, causing you to pick up interference and noise.  Are they powered speakers by any chance?  Try a pair of headphones in the same jack for a while instead, and see if the issues continue, and let us know the results. :)

Comment: The cable maybe picking up interference.  First, try moving the cable away from other cables as much as possible.  I don't know if you have a generic cable or a high quality cable, but high quality(aka expensive) cables have better shielding.

Comment: @techie007 It really seems like a grounding issue now because I realized that even if the jack is unplugged from the PC, I can still hear buzzing. How do you usually fix the grounding issue?

Comment: @techie007 Hmmm, upon googling it appears this is a common issue Logitech z523. I think the problem is with the connector of subwoofer to right tweeter, I tried to tighten it a bit, it seems to alleviate the issue. I will observe more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sound you would be using a Realtek sound driver for your sound card. If so then first should try to default all sound settings to normal and then confirm if it's working. If it doesn't work then try a new build of Realtek drivers(can google it, will not take much time) and install them. Also if check to see if your woofer is working perfectly so that maybe sometimes the vibrations are because of the increase in bass and treble.
Also if you had the problem from some time then maybe your speakers are faulty or maybe your 3.5mm jack is defected. Try changing the wire for some effects.

Comment: How do you know he's supposed to use realtek? Using the wrong drivers can damage certain hardware, or make Windows unstable

Comment: I don't know, I just guessed, if I am wrong than you can just install the drivers for your device(if you know the driver name).